# EventKit without using Calendar or Reminders App

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, events, eventkit

I am curious if there is a way to use the capabilities of EventKit - creating events, recurrence rules, etc. - without actually having to interface with the Calendar and Reminders apps?

A little more detail on requirements and such:

1. A user launches my app, and creates a new event-style entry there
2. The event-style entry does **not** actually appear in the Reminders or Calendar app
3. My app can still access the event-style entry and its related options

Note: There could/would be a preference option to make the created event-style entries visible in the Reminders/Calendar app.

Basically, to achieve the ability to use or not use the Reminders/Calendar apps, I don't want to have to write two versions of the code - one using my own EventKit-esque implementation - and the other using the *real* EventKit framework APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope—EventKit is designed to work with the existing calendar stores that Calendar and Reminders have access to. If you want to create events that they don’t know about, you have to roll your own calendar store. You can certainly model it after EventKit for relative ease of switching between the two, but you’ll need to reimplement whatever parts of the API’s functionality you’re planning to use.